# Getting error saying no match for 'operator=='. Trying to get if statement to realize if user answered 'n' then print message

Tags: c++, if-statement

Code is diagnostic program, asks y or n questions then using if statements will give diagnosis. Asks four yes or no questions and if first two answers are n then diagnosis is unknown but if first to are yes and third is yes user has a cold. I haven't typed out full code yet but all questions are shown and first if statement there back an error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

// variables
string runnyNose;
string congestedNose;
string achyBody;
string severeHeadache;
double bodyTemp;

// Print program name
cout << "==================================" << endl;
cout << "Welcome to Dr. Plympton's Office!" << endl;
cout << "==================================" << endl;


// get runny nose symptom
cout << "Do you have a runny nose (Enter 'y' or 'n')? ";
cin >> runnyNose;

// get congestion symptom
cout << "Are you expeeriencing nasal congestion (Enter 'y' or 'n')? ";
cin >> congestedNose;

// get achy symptom
cout << "Are you feeling achy all over (Enter 'y' or 'n')? ";
cin >> achyBody;

// get headache symptom
cout << "Do you have a severe headache behind or below one eye (Enter 'y' or 'n')? ";
cin >> severeHeadache;

// get temp
cout << "What is your temperature (Enter the number)? ";
cin >> bodyTemp;

if (runnyNose == 'n')
   cout << "Unknown: Sorry, you need to see a specialist. Your bill is $40.00. " << 
endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't compare a `std::string` to a single `char`. Either check the first character of the string, with `if (runnyNose[0] == 'n')` or test against a string literal with `if (runnyNose == "n")` (note the double quotes).

Comment: What question do you have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

try to change the data-type from string to char. You can compare them with **strcmp** or only with **==**.